# Getting the system audio levels in Java

Tags: java, audio, system, system-sounds

How does one get the master volume in Java? I want to make a program that displays (**NOT CHANGE**) this value (probably on a `JProgressBar` or something similar) as a percentage of the maximum setting. I might also want to display the current sound level as a percentage of highest possible sound level, but this is not needed.

Comment: As a side note, don't use a progress bar for that.  The master sound level is not a measure of progress, and some OSes will draw an animating bar that will not be appropriate for measuring the sound level.

Comment: As what is it measured, then?

Comment: A progress bar is a bar that shows the progress of a long-lived task (eg copying files)

Comment: No. A progress bar shows a bar that is a certain percentage of the length of the whole object. One must not think that it can only grow.

Comment: I didn't say that it can only grow… But read http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html - "A component that visually displays the progress of some task." That component is not made to display a value that can be modified by the user. (While `JSlider` is)

Comment: I do not want the user to modify it. I just want the user to see the volume Note that in my question I said "displays". I did not mention being able to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure, but you could have a look at the ([Java Media Framework - JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)). You are able to control the sound via that library, so I would assume you can get the details about it too. It might just be the application's sound level, so I might be wrong.

Comment: seems like a library for visual effects (i.e. audio/video editing)

Comment: No, I have used it before to write an audio streamer / player.

Comment: I'm sure it's great for that, too, but it doesn't help ME

Comment: How, coding wise, can it be used to measure the system's current sound level?

Answer (score 2):

Although `JProgressBar` is not used for this
This might Help

```
package test;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class SoundMeter {

JFrame j;

public SoundMeter() {
    j = new JFrame("SoundMeter");
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setLayout(new BoxLayout(j.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    printMixersDetails();
    j.setVisible(true);
}
public void printMixersDetails(){
    javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    System.out.println("There are " + mixers.length + " mixer info objects");  
    for(int i=0;i<mixers.length;i++){
        Mixer.Info mixerInfo = mixers[i];
        System.out.println("Mixer Name:"+mixerInfo.getName());
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
        Line.Info[] lineinfos = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        for(Line.Info lineinfo : lineinfos){
            System.out.println("line:" + lineinfo);
            try {
                Line line = mixer.getLine(lineinfo);
                line.open();
                if(line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME)){
                    FloatControl control = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
                    System.out.println("Volume:"+control.getValue());   
                    JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
                    // if you want to set the value for the volume 0.5 will be 50%
                    // 0.0 being 0%
                    // 1.0 being 100%
                    //control.setValue((float) 0.5);
                    int value = (int) (control.getValue()*100);
                    pb.setValue(value);
                    j.add(new JLabel(lineinfo.toString()));
                    j.add(pb);
                    j.pack();
                }
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SoundMeter();
}
}
```

Comment: It appears to only measure and set the volume of the application, not the system.

Answer (score 0):

Nico is right.
Here is an article and example that might help you.

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jenut3_ch17/index.html
http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jenut3_ch17/examples/SoundPlayer.java

Comment: Note: both links are now dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could be a little less abrasive rather than say "Does not help me".

Otherwise, here is the big picture, using the Sound API mentioned by AlexR's example: (there are a lot of practical details [on that forum thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492931/java/java/Adjusting-master-volume-Windows-XP), and there is some Oracle documentation for [Processing Audio with Controls](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html))

- Once you get a [`Line`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html) object that represents the sound output line that you wish to control, it is rather trivial to get the volume control:

  ```
  line.open(); // May be necessary if the line is not already opened.
  FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) masterLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
  ```
- Getting the "Master `Line`" object is, at best, platform-dependant. You will have to list the [`Mixer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html)s and the `Line`s at runtime using the [`AudioSystem`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) static methods in order to determine which line you want. It can also happen that the master line will not support the volume control directly, but only through a `CompoundControl`. (through a hierarchy that is, you guessed it, platform-dependant).

Comment: using `line = (Port)AudioSystem.getMixer(null).getLine(Port.Info.LINE_IN);`, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: LINE_IN source port`

Comment: @Supuhstar: 1. I suspect you meant to write `((Port) AudioSystem.getMixer(null)).getLine(Port.Info.LINE_IN);` - which would have thrown a `ClassCastException`. 2. There is no guarantee that invoking `AudioSystem.getMixer(null)` will yield the `Port` that you want to get - the computer cannot guess what you want. 3. I believe the only reliable way is by enumerating some subset of the system's `Line`s or the `Mixer`s by using the `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()` and similar other methods, and checking each one. 4. If you had read the linked forum thread, I would not have had to write points 2 and 3.