# Java mute system Sound

Tags: java, audio, system, mute

I'm currently Working on something like a PC Media Remote control. I have been working for days now and can't find a solution to my problem. I tried many things for Example

The Java sound class:
[Can Java Sound be used to control the system volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume)

I got this working for me but it doesn't mute the system sound, it only seems to mute the "Java Applikation sound". I set all Volumes for every Device to 0.0 but sound would be still on. Also I got on none of my device a control for "MASTER_GAIN". How is this Possible?

Also I tried to use a robot to send media Hotkeys. But it seems that the robot cant handle only normal keys. [How to type 'a' using robot.pressKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530615/how-to-type-a-using-robot-presskey)

So after that I tried Intellitype which I also found somewhre linked on Stack Overflow:
http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/

with this its possible for me to be informed if the media button on my keyboard is pressed, but I couldn't find a way to send that key to the system.

the question now is:

Is there a way to mute the system sound with that Key trigger and when how?
Also why did the Sound API didn't let me handle the system sound? seems like a few People on the net got it working.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions (none accepted) on this post: [getting-the-system-sound-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211439/getting-the-system-sound-in-java?rq=1). Please upvote any you find helpful as the OP on that question wasn't very forthcoming.

Comment: great tutorial with sound but either i cant find the right post nor dos one of this post really fix the problem... with the code suggested i still only control the "app-sound" :(

Comment: I thought [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236751/758831) and associated comments seemed like a well thought out description of what you would need to do. I've not done it personally though.

Comment: Hmmm... some pretty categorical "no you can't" answers here [can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume?lq=1) (except the poster that called out to his C++ process to handle the mechanics). - Just seen you reference this in your post.

Comment: thanks for all your help but i gave up now... i fiixxed my problem by calling some external C++ code wich handles the request :)